# How to make a clean code but same results as my code? javafx hbox array for loop

Tags: arrays, for-loop, javafx, substring

There are 6 buttons, each button have an OnMouseEntered handler that changes the Button's text to "Click Me!" Also has an OnMouseExited handler that changes the Button's text back to its original text.

Is any method could enable the code as clean as possible? and how? Thank you very much! 
There are loads of repeated code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyGUI extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        VBox vb = new VBox();
        Button[] btn = new Button[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            btn[i] = new Button("Button" + (i + 1));
        }

        vb.getChildren().addAll(btn);
        root.getChildren().addAll(lv, vb);

        btn[0].setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
            btn[0].setText("Click Me!");
        });
        btn[1].setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
            btn[1].setText("Click Me!");
        });
        btn[2].setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
            btn[2].setText("Click Me!");
        });
        btn[3].setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
            btn[3].setText("Click Me!");
        });
        btn[4].setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
            btn[4].setText("Click Me!");
        });
        btn[5].setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
            btn[5].setText("Click Me!");
        });
        btn[0].setOnMouseExited(e -> {
            btn[0].setText("Button1");
        });
        btn[1].setOnMouseExited(e -> {
            btn[1].setText("Button2");
        });
        btn[2].setOnMouseExited(e -> {
            btn[2].setText("Button3");
        });
        btn[3].setOnMouseExited(e -> {
            btn[3].setText("Button4");
        });
        btn[4].setOnMouseExited(e -> {
            btn[4].setText("Button5");
        });
        btn[5].setOnMouseExited(e -> {
            btn[5].setText("Button6");
        });

        Scene MScene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setTitle("My Button"); 
        primaryStage.setScene(MScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various solutions depending on the requirement, e. g.:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyGUI extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        HBox root = new HBox();
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        Button[] buttons = new Button[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

            String text = "Button" + (i + 1);

            Button button = new Button(text);

            button.setOnMouseEntered( e -> button.setText("Click Me!"));
            button.setOnMouseExited( e -> button.setText(text));

            buttons[i] = button;

        }

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(buttons);
        root.getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setTitle("My Button");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much for the method.